# build docker image of nextjs with ISR

Tags: docker, next.js, moralis

I am trying to build a docker image of my nextjs application that uses ISR.  The pages connects to a 3rd party (moralis) api through https on port 2053 to get dynamic data.  I can build the application locally.  However, when I try to build it with docker, it appears that it's timing out trying to acccess the moralis server.  Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This question is missing some code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like networking issue, check if can ping outside of container.